# How to create raspberry pi image for use on QEMU

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, raspberry-pi, qemu

I am looking to run a service on a raspberry pi VM in QEMU. What am I hoping to do is:

1. Get an image, such as 2021-buster-lite
2. update it
3. install the packages I want
4. image it so that it can be used on QEMU.

I'm not sure if image is the right word to use here but I want to be able to spin up a VM from that image and have it be updated with the packages I want. Also, I am using Fedora if that helps.

Are there any easy and free ways to do this?

Comment: A Pi is a piece of hardware that may not necessarily be easy to emulate (it's ARM, and has some fairly specialised hardware not found in the commonly emulated PC-like targets). Is there any particular piece of software you are trying to run? Anything that a plain Debian VM would not satisfy?

Comment: The project I am creating specifically requires a Pi. I wish to spin up multiple Pis using docker compose and because of the processor incompatibility, I am running QEMU inside a container. It has been based on this project: https://github.com/lukechilds/dockerpi. My first aim is to run an apache2 server and hopefully expand it out later.

Comment: On second look, [qemu does emulate a decent number of the peripherals](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/arm/raspi.html) so you may have some luck there.

Comment: The [raspberrypi.se] site [seems to have a few answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=emulate+raspberry+pi+on+linux+site:raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) to this, specifically https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117234/how-to-emulate-raspberry-pi-in-qemu

Comment: I'm sorry I should have specified, I have been able to emulate the raspberry pi in QEMU successfully. What I'm currently trying to do is get a webserver (and other software) to start automatically when the VM boots up. My plan was to get an updated custom image in it to minimise the amount of work the VM would have to do when it boots.